# Use two images in one location by drag

Tags: javascript, css, web

When I drag on these images at [kenh14.vn](http://kenh14.vn/la-cool/chiem-nguong-cac-buc-hinh-canh-doi-thuong-tai-hien-tren-anime-p1-2014080905424720.chn), It will show another image.
Could you please tell me which technique are used in this page like this:

[image]
p/s: I don't know keywords to google it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the place to ask these sort of questions. But since you asked, that is a jQuery plugin, you can look at this one for example: http://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty

Please go over this section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks @odedta. You save me a lot.